# Confusion about Jointly Gaussian

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, random-variables, normal-distribution, gaussian

1. From [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/428058/is-the-joint-distribution-of-two-linear-combinations-of-gaussians-still-a-multiv?noredirect=1&lq=1), it says that, linear combination of two Gaussian distribution, are always Gaussians.
2. However, Let  be standard normal and =±1 with probability 1/2 each, independently of . Let =. Then  is also standard normal, but =+ is exactly equal to zero with probability 1/2 and is equal to 2 with probability 1/2.

But (2) contradicts with (1). Am I missing anythings?

Comment: interesting... You logics seem to be correct, but I still think both (1) and (2) are true..

Answer (score 2):

The simplest case is when you take linear combinations of *independent* Gaussian random variables, these will be Gaussian. However, $X$ and $Y$ are not independent. A more general case in which linear combinations of correlated Gaussian random variables are Gaussian is if $X$ and $Y$ are bivariate Gaussian (aka *jointly* Gaussian). You can read more about this difference between (1) $X$ and $Y$ are both Gaussian and (2) $X$ and $Y$ are bivariate (jointly) Gaussian here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multivariate_normal_distribution

Essentially, there are many ways for variables to correlated. Being jointly Gaussian random variables is a special way for Gaussian variables to be correlated that implies this property we've discussed. In fact, jointly Gaussian variables can actually be defined by this property that all linear combinations are normally distributed.

Comment: Wait... (1) also holds for non independent cases.

Comment: This holds if either independent random variables or if $X$ and $Y$ are bivariate Gaussian. Check out: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normally_distributed_and_uncorrelated_does_not_imply_independent

Comment: Yes, I think you change the word "independent" into "bivariate" or "jointly" or "multivariate" because as it stands, the reasoning in your answer is not correct. (Linear combinations of non-independent Gaussians is also sometimes a Gaussian.)

Comment: Just a technicality, "You need" should read "In case"

Comment: Thanks @E-A and @ VictorZurkowski, I've incorporated your feedback!

Answer (score 0):

Linear combinations of jointly Gaussians (also known as multivariate Gaussians) are always Gaussian; however, X and Y are not jointly Gaussian. (One of the easiest ways to define a joint Gaussian $X$ is to say that $X = AZ + b$ where $A$ is some matrix, $b$ is some vector and $Z$ is a vector of i.i.d. Gaussians.)

Comment: Sorry, what do you mean by jointly Gaussian. ...?

Comment: I wrote one way in the parantheses. The canonical way to define a Gaussian is by its characteristic function, but you can use the alternate definition I wrote in the paranthesis. When the random variables admit a joint density, you can use the fact that the density of it has a certain form)